# Some USB Ports dont support usb hub after login

Tags: keyboard, usb, filevault

I have a problem that seems to be a combination of other problems mentioned here & on the apple support forums. I've tried al the fixes I could find but am still coming up short.

I have a USB-C Hub that I use for a second monitor (HDMI) and a USB Keyboard for my 2019 Macbook Pro. Everything works fine if I use one of the two USB ports on the left side, but I get a weird pattern of problems if I try to use one of them on the right side:

- If I plug it in on the right side, neither the keyboard or the monitor are ever recognized at first (the USB keyboard has lights that turn on if it's powered so it's definitely just not being recognized at all).
- If I leave it plugged in, sometimes (not always) the computer will eventually recognize the keyboard after ~10m or so but never the monitor
- If I reboot the computer *before resetting NVRAM/SMC* the keyboard and monitor are not recognized, but the keyboard may be recognized ~10m later as before
- After resetting NVRAM and SMC the keyboard is reliably recognized after restarting, and works when I type my password to log in, but as soon as I log in the keyboard stops being recognized and seems to be less likely to be detected after some delay than before. The monitor is never recognized.

So in summary -- the left side USB ports work normally, but the right side USB ports work very selectively and are not fixed by resetting NVRAM/SMC. I've read a few posts that suggest it might be an issue with FileVault, but those are all a few years old so I don't know how relevant they are for a machine w/ the T2 chip and latest version of filevault. This problem has persisted for several versions an was definitely still true when i was still running Catalina.

Here are the other guides/threads/posts/etc. i've read and tried the solutions from:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8048517
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8038548
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7212849
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4132214
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251666003
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7212849

Info about my machine:

- Macbook Pro 15-inch 2019
- macOS version 11.2.1
- 2.4GHz 8-core Intel Core i9
- Filevault enabled

Also posted this over here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252492736

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) As for your question, I see you've been quite thorough in trying to use a process of elimination to get to the source of your problem. One thing you don't mention though is how your MBP was being charged during these various steps? Left side v right side. Directly or through the Hub? Does not having it on charge make any difference as opposed to having it on charge? And does the MBP charge just fine from either port on the right side? Finally, do the right side ports work normally when hardware is connected directly to them (i.e. not via the Hub)?

Comment: Charging doesn't seem to matter, charging on left side, right side, or power disconnected the same problems are true -- typically i charge on the right side (I want to move both things to the right side because my monitor has to be on the left!). I don't charge through the hub because it can get hot, but that also doesn't change the problems. The MBP charges fine from all the ports. The problems are ... different when directly connected but not gone, i can test and try to characterize that if it would be helpful. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Ok, and do the right-side ports work okay when devices are connected directly (i.e. not via a hub, dock etc)?

Comment: The problems are ... different when directly connected (not through hub) but not gone -- the keyboard will sometimes be recognized but it seems to be pretty random. Computer busy with something rn so can't try resetting NVRAM or anything but can do if that would be helpful.